# Function not working when authenticating to google cloud platform

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a code that sets the 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' variable in the os.envrion to a json file that include my authentication to access a bucket in the google cloud platform and download parquet data from it.

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'file.json'

    def extract(self, config: CloudStorageConfig) -> pd.DataFrame:
        path = f'gs://{config.bucket}/{config.blob}'
        data = pd.read_parquet(path)
        return data
```

For my colleague this code works but for me it throws the below error.

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host storage.googleapis.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')]
```

I have created another alternative function that downloads the data for the time being.

```
    def alt_extract(config,
                    json_filepath=r'file.json', filename=None) -> pd.DataFrame:
        if json_filepath is None:
            raise KeyError('Credentials are missing')

        with open(json_filepath) as source:
            info = json.load(source)

        storage_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(info)
        storage_client = storage.Client(project=constants.GCS_PROJECT_ID, credentials=storage_credentials)

        bucket = storage_client.bucket(config.bucket)
        blob = bucket.blob(config.blob)
        blob.download_to_filename(filename)

        data = pd.read_parquet(filename)
        return data
```

However, when the code goes to PROD, I would still need the first function to be used. Does anyone know why I an getting this error?

Comment: Do not use service account key file. It will solve a lot of issue, it's insecure and it's a bad practice. I recommend to have a look on the ADC: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc

Comment: @eredinbreaccglas, did the previous comment address your concern?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, unfortunately could not solve my issue yet. But for this exact project, I have to use a key file. Therefore, I need to solve my issue in a different manner.

Comment: @eredinbreaccglas, My comment does not solve the issue, but will solve further one, and  Cloud Functions does not need to have a credential.json file (it's an anti pattern!!). Therefore, working correctly with credential could solve more than expected.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks bunches for the resources on ADC, I will need to implement it in other projects. For this particular one though, do you think some SSL certification adjustment by the IT department could be causing the error?

Comment: SSL error is strange for a managed container (Cloud Functions runs inside a container built by Google CLoud). Maybe a wrong Pandas version. Or try to deploy Cloud Functions 2nd gen